# How to hide a opened mat menu when other mat menu is openes

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

When one of the mat menu in the navbar is clicked the other mat menu which is already opened should be closed. How to hide the mat menu's

```
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu001" class="menu" >Assessments</button>
  <mat-menu #menu001="matMenu" class="m2" overlapTrigger="false">
    <a id="dialogUpsert01" class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/b/dialog/upsert']">Dialog Questions</a>
    <a id="dialogSearch02" class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/b/dialog/search']">Search Questions</a>
    <a id="dialogAuthor01" class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/b/bot/meeting-request']">Meeting Request</a>
  </mat-menu>

  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="menu">Assessments2</button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="m2" overlapTrigger="false">
    <a id="createQuestionid" class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/ad/q/upsert']">Create Questions</a>
    <a id="searchQuestionsId" class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/ad/search-question']">Search Questions</a>
  </mat-menu>
```

In this case,a mat menu2 is triggerd when mat menu 1 is opened. Then mat menu 1 should be hidden.

Kindly do help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MatMenuTrigger).

You can find an output event called **menuOpened**, that you can attach to each mat-menu, which will help you to know which menu opened and with the help of

> **@Viewchild decorator you can toggle the other one.**

for example, it might look like this:

- in the template

  ```
  <mat-menu #menu1="matMenu" (menuOpened)="menu1Opend()">

  </mat-menu>
  <mat-menu #menu2="matMenu" (menuOpened)="menu2Opend()">

  </mat-menu>
  ```
- in the class

  ```
  export class MyComponent {
   @ViewChild('menu1') menu1: MatMenu;
   @ViewChild('menu2') menu2: MatMenu;
   menu1Opend(){
       if(menu2.menuOpen) menu2.closeMenu()
   }
   menu2Opend(){
       if(menu1.menuOpen) menu1.closeMenu()
   }
  }
  ```

If the two menus in the different component you might use a singleton service.

Comment: A more interesting solution would be a DRYer version of this